# How to detect if iOS UIViewController is being interacted with or touched

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, touchesended

I have a specific UIViewController for which I want to block the idleTimer processing done by iOS. I know that I can set:  `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true`
However, I want to be able to set a timer to re-enable the normal system idle timer processing after a fixed amount of time, thus I can keep the screen on for a minimum amount of time. The nature of the app is such that you would have a view open and use it for reference/reading for a longish time.

The KEY POINT is that I want the timer to restart every time the user touches the screen or interacts with the device. So I need to be able to detect if the user does anything so I can rest the time.

I tried to override the touchesEnded method in the controller, however testing showed that the method is never called. Any ideas would be welcomed (in swift 3:)

Comment: Do you need to detect touch of the particular `UIView` or `detect `touch` of the screen when app using `Background App Referesh` ?

Comment: I need to detect touch for screen only, not background refresh. I also need it done in code. I want to detect for the whole controller's view (and by extension the sub-views), not just a specific view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 3.0 :-**

Need to detect touch of the particular view without `IBOutlet`, then select that particular `UIView` then goto `Attributes Inspector -> View -> tag` and set `Integer` as tag whatever need.

[image]

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first

    let tag = touch?.view?.tag
    if tag == 1{
        //Do More....
    }else{
    //......
    }

}
```

If you need to check with `IBOutlet`, then do like as below.

Here, `@IBOutlet var diamondView: UIView!`

```
if touch?.view == self.diamondView{

    //Do More....
}else{
//......
}
```

**Update : Scroll View**

If you need to detect touch of the scroll view then use `UITapGestureRecognizer`. By story board drag and drop to to of the `UIViewController` and set `delegate` and `gestureRecognizers` for `scroll view` to `UITapGestureRecognizer`. After that just create action for `UITapGestureRecognizer` like as below screenshot.
[image]

**Adding UITapGesture Programmatically :-**

Also below code works fine without do like above screenshot.

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.actionTapOnScrollView(sender:)))
    self.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


}

@objc private func actionTapOnScrollView(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("user Touched")
}
```

Comment: I've tried to override `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` but they are not being called for he controller. The main view inside the controllers view is a `UIScrollView` that dominates most of the window.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RAJAMOHAN-S. I was hoping for something more lower level (that didn't involve sub-classing). My answer to this questions tells you how I did end up doing it.

Comment: @zkon , Thanks, if you don't hesitate send me the code snippet through skype on my profile. I will send back with proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved this by doing a composite solution to what @RAJAMOHAN-S suggested.

1. I added a `UIGestureRecognizer` to the controllers view. Using this I could pick up if there was a tap anywhere in the view and thus reset my timer.

   `view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTappedHandler)))`

   The `viewTappedHandler` method set the timer I needed.
2. I made my `UIController` a delegate for the `UIScrollView` by adding the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol to the controller's class declaration.

   Then I implemented: `scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` and again set the time. This picks up movements in the scroll view that the tap gesture doesn't pick up.
3. Finally, because my scroll view contained other views that can open the keyboard, I also needed to register for keyboard notifications and again set the timer for each occurrence.

   `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidHide), name: .UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidChange), name: .UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame, object: nil)`

I'm not completely happy with this as tapping on the keyboard keys is not detected, but I'm not expecting this to be a real issue for this app.

PS I also removed the observers on the keyboard and clear the timer on `deinit`.